# How to programmatically execute xcm message from Patachain A to execute an extrinsic on Parachain B

Tags: polkadot-js, xcm, substrate-parachain-template

I have a local relaychain setup with 2 parachains `Parachain A` and `Parachain B`  .
I will like to execute an XCM message from `Parachain A` to execute an extrinsic on `Parachain B` using the `Transact instruction`.How do I achieve this programmatically without using `polkadot.js` webapp. Do I need to add `pallet-xcm` as a dependency , then write code in `Parachain A` to create the instruction and then call send which is on `pallet-xcm`?
Is there any sample code that does this or detailed instruction on this or programmatically executing xcm?

// UPDATE

When sending Transact XCM Instruction from parachain A, how do I specify (or how does the xcm-executor know) the pallet / pallet id  on the target Parachain B which contains the extrinsic to be executed, or is it not required?

for example.
The following Transact Xcm message is sent from parachain A to execute an extrinsic called ping defined in the cumulus-ping pallet on Parachain B.
In the xcm message below, I do not see the cumulus-ping pallet or the index of the cumulus-ping pallet specified in the XCM instruction. so how does XCM determine the pallet / module where the  ping extrinsic on Parachain B is located?
The code I attached below is from the cumulus repo [here](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/a05c09c6d525d7ab62e95643666154b8b0abb546/parachains/pallets/ping/src/lib.rs#L206)

// This is Parachain A, which sends the xcm message

```
send_xcm::<T::XcmSender>(
                    (Parent, Junction::Parachain(para.into())).into(),
                    Xcm(vec![Transact {
                        origin_kind: OriginKind::Native,
                        require_weight_at_most: Weight::from_parts(1_000, 1_000),
                        call: <T as Config>::RuntimeCall::from(Call::<T>::ping {
                            seq,
                            payload: payload.clone().to_vec(),
                        })
                        .encode()
                        .into(),
                    }]),
                )
```

// This is the runtime of patachain B which contains cumulus-ping pallet which has the ping extrinsic

```
construct_runtime! {
    pub enum Runtime where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = generic::Block<Header, sp_runtime::OpaqueExtrinsic>,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config, Event<T>},
        ...
        Spambot: cumulus_ping::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>} = 99,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no detailed instructions explaining how to use transact, but there is an [demo article](https://medium.com/oak-blockchain/tutorial-polkadot-cross-chain-message-passing-xcmp-demo-with-ping-pallet-f53397158ab4) by OAK network that explains the working of `XCMP` and in that they have used [cumulus_ping](https://github.com/imstar15/cumulus/tree/master/polkadot-parachains/pallets/ping) that is using `transact instruction` [here](https://github.com/imstar15/cumulus/blob/master/polkadot-parachains/pallets/ping/src/lib.rs#L105C11-L105C11). It helped me a lot in understanding the working of `transact instruction` I hope it helps you too.

Comment: When sending the Transact XCM Instruction from parachain A, how is the target pallet Id which contains the extrinsic to be executed specified? I have updated the question

Comment: I am also currently doing R&D on transact instruction , so I am also not sure how it identifies the pallet, for now what I understand is that we need to specify the transact instruction in the same pallet on which we want on other chain.

Comment: Do you mean that the pallets on both receiving (pallet which initiates the xcm) and destination (pallet which contains the extrinsic) chain should have same name ?